Reading results of a Sub Query in SOQL Salesforce
I am new to Apex and SOQL.
I want to get data from Account and Contacts of Contacts  using SOQL , give the results to a List.
From the List, I want to  'Get' data from the results Outer Query Accounts and from the the inner query (from Contacts).  How do I do this?

This is what I tried, I do not know how to proceed further.

integer counter = 0;
string accountId;
string accountName;
List<Account> myAccts = [SELECT Id, Name, (Select Id, Name from Contacts) from Account];
for(Account i :myAccts) {
    
    
    //System.debug(i);
  Account currentAccount =   myAccts.get(counter);
    
    accountId = currentAccount.Id;
    accountName = currentAccount.Name;
    System.debug('This is the current account record---' + accountName);
    counter = counter+1;
}


// SOQL to retrieve Accounts and related Contacts
List<Account> myAccts = [SELECT Id, Name, (Select Id, Name from Contacts) from Account];

// Loop through each Account
for (Account acct : myAccts) {
   
    // Example of referencing Account field
    system.debug(acct.Name);
    
    // Loop through each related Contact
    for (Contact con : acct.Contacts) {
        
        // Example of referencing Contact field
        system.debug(con.Name);
    }

}


Thank you very much Scarnegie !  I am very grateful.
